# How to specify the ip address SendGrid uses to send Webhook Events from

Tags: sendgrid, webhooks

Is there a way to specify the ip address SendGrid uses or identify the ip address or range that they use to send Webhook Event responses?
I need to restrict a server to only those external calls.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this and it's unlikely to be a sustainable strategy since the number of servers and their address is going to change. You might be able to do a [rDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) lookup. But the easiest way might be to implement basic auth over https as described here https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html#-Setup